# Is it correct to say "how far someone achieved"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Is it correct to say "**how far someone achieved**"? By saying this phrase I mean to say, how much the society has achieved its goals.

> Human Development Index is an index that indicates **how far society has
> achieved** considering three dimensions of health, education, and living
> standards. The higher the index is, the longer the life expectancy is.

Is it better to say **how much** or **how** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since "far" suggests distance, it might be better to use "how far society has come", or stick with your other suggestion, "how much society has achieved".

Also, your first sentence has 3 cognate words in a row:
Index, index, and indicate. You could say
The Human Development Index shows how much...